# Input Radio buttons are processed in Cartthrob only according to their position

Tags: cartthrob, forms

I have a big doubt about Carttrob.

**Here a simple form code:**

```
 {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form    allow_user_price="yes" return="{template_group}/view_cart"}

                    <input name="price" autocomplete="false"                       
                          type="number"placeholder="" />


                        <label for="15">15</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="price" value="15" id="15"/>

                        <label for="30">30</label>
                        <input  type="radio" name="price" value="30" id="30"/>

                        <label for="45">45</label>
                        <input  type="radio" name="price" value="45" id="45"/>


                <label class="clear">
                    <textarea placeholder="None" name="item_options[donation_note]" ></textarea>
                </label>
                <button type="submit" class="button">Add to Cart</button>

    {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

if [image]
**is placed before** the **radio buttons** block code `<input type="radio" name="price" value="x" id="x"/>`

**it works fine**, because in the **In the mysite/donate/view_cart** page,  appears:

[image]

but if [image] is **placed after the block code** `<input type="radio" name="price" value="x" id="x"/>`

here the simple form code **modified**, the **input type number is placed after**.

```
 {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form    allow_user_price="yes" return="{template_group}/view_cart"}



                            <label for="15">15</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="price" value="15" id="15"/>

                            <label for="30">30</label>
                            <input  type="radio" name="price" value="30" id="30"/>

                            <label for="45">45</label>
                            <input  type="radio" name="price" value="45" id="45"/>

                        <input name="price" autocomplete="false"                       
                              type="number"placeholder="" />



                    <label class="clear">
                        <textarea placeholder="None" name="item_options[donation_note]" ></textarea>
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Add to Cart</button>

        {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

The `<input type="radio" name="price" value="x" id="x"/>`  buttons **are not processed**,  In the **mysite/donate/view_cart** appears:[image]

So the **input radio buttons are not processed** if they are placed before the **input type="number**. It appears **R$0.00**. Only the **input type="number** is processed, **the radio buttons not**.

Why the **radio buttons** are **processed** only if they are **placed after the** **input type="number** ? A process priority problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is not the better solution, but thanks to the **Source Ordering** (from the Zurb Foundation framework) the order columns could be shifted.

```
                <fieldset class="small-8 small-push-4 columns">
                                    <input name="price" class="" style="width: 9rem; margin-bottom: 0;"
                                           onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)"
                                           oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)"
                                           autocomplete="false"
                                           placeholder = "Livre"
                                           type = "number"
                                           min = "1"
                                           max = "9999999" />
                                </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="defined_price" class="small-4 small-pull-8 columns">
                                    <!--<label for="doar_{valor_1}">{valor_1}</label>-->
                                    <input name="price"  type="radio" value="{valor_1}" id="{valor_1}" id="doar_{valor_1}"><label for="{valor_1}">{valor_1}</label>
                                    <input name="price" type="radio"  value="{valor_2}" id="{valor_2}" id="doar_{valor_2}"><label for="{valor_2}">{valor_2}</label>
                                    <input name="price" type="radio"  value="{valor_3}" id="{valor_3}" id="doar_{valor_3}"><label for="{valor_3}">{valor_3}</label>
                    </fieldset>
```

The two display fieldsets are inverted, so the **input type="number"** is placed before the **radio input**, but thanks to the Zurb Foundation Grid css command.